# Troubleshooting a Script, to copy a sheet to multiple spreadsheets in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a total noobie such that I am not entirely sure how to ask this question. I used this walkthrough and script to try to copy a sheet to multiple spreadsheets in a folder in Google Drive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3pE7ENwjpQ

This video shows how to copy one sheet to multiple spreadsheets at the same time. The link to the script is here: https://script.google.com/u/2/home/projects/1XlgYs8056jvq4dbfaEMxCgmu9L0epXGvfVZ29tx_5-jN-tNcYwhwmjtX/edit

I followed the instructions in the video to input the tab # of the tab to be copied into the script (tried multiple versions, like including and excluding hidden tabs, etc.) and changed the title of the copied tab as mentioned in the video.

However, running the script in a test folder, the tabs weren't copied over into the spreadsheets in that folder. Can anyone provide any tips for troubleshooting or updating the script to make it function as intended to copy a sheet to all spreadsheets within a Google Drive folder?

Please help!

Comment: [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))

Comment: Hi ! I have tested the script you provided and it worked as expected copying the first sheet of your Spreadsheet and pasting it in the rest of the Spreadsheets in the folder with the name ```THIS WAS COPIED```. Was this what you wanted to achieve? Could you please share the code you are using without including any sensitive data to check that the one you are using is well written? Also, what do you mean by ```to input the tab # of the tab to be copied into the script```.

Comment: Mateo, Yes that's what I wanted to achieve, but I don't know why it didn't work for me. I used the script exactly as it was from that link, just copy-pasted, and it didn't work for me, even without changing anything. It says 'execution completed' but none of the spreadsheets in the same folder have the tab that I tried to copied over?

Comment: Did you authorise your script the first time you run it? Is the Spreadsheet that you will get the sheet from **on the same folder** than the rest of the Spreadsheets it should be copied to? Does the folder have any special characteristic that we should be aware of (shared, root, etc)? Thanks !

Comment: Authorize, yes I signed into the account with the test folder when opening the script editor. The test source spreadsheet and the two test destination spreadsheets are all in one test folder on this account's google drive. and only that account (owner) has permissions to the folder.
Strange you were able to use the script but I can't figure out why I can't get it to work! I have even tried signing out of all accounts except for that one.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share with me the script project you are using without providing any sensitive data on it so that I can test your script specifically ? Thanks !

Comment: I used the script at that link: https://script.google.com/u/2/home/projects/1XlgYs8056jvq4dbfaEMxCgmu9L0epXGvfVZ29tx_5-jN-tNcYwhwmjtX/edit
I tried it without changing anything and it still didn't work. I tried it with some changes too (changing the tab # after source.getSheets() and changing the tab name/text of the THIS WAS COPIED), neither worked.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for providing the script. Is this a [bounded script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)? Remember that for ```getActiveSpreadsheet()``` to work this must be a bounded script.